# Removing white space around the divs

Tags: wordpress, removing-whitespace

So my question is how to remove white space around the divs. When I create posts in my blog homepage, they all are different size because I made that div size would be the size of the image - http://jsfiddle.net/AL547/

```
html:
<div class="container">
    <div class="post" style="width:150px; height:60px">post<p>I dont want the white space here</p></div>
    <div class="post" style="width:120px; height:80px">post<p>I dont want the white space here</p></div>
    <div class="post" style="width:140px; height:110px" >post</div>
    <div class="post" style="width:150px; height:80px">post</div>
    <div class="post" style="width:80px; height:120px">post</div>
    <div class="post" style="width:150px; height:80px">post</div>
</div>

css:
.container {
    margin-top: 60px;
    border:4px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    min-height:300px;
    width:500px;    
}
.post {
    margin:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;

}

p {
     color:red;
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

My final webpage look I want to be like here : http://themeforest.net/item/blogphix-an-endless-scrolling-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/3666866

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into tools like Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ or Isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Looks like the site you linked uses Masonry.

I'm pretty sure this can't be done without any javascript.

Comment: Hey pstenstrm, the links show excatly what I wanted! I knew that without javascript I couldnt do that, thanks fot the links.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you may add min-height to your .post so it makes all divs at least specified height, like this one:

.post {min-height: 120px;}

Otherwise you may use jQuery to calculate the highest value and then apply similar style to your .post divs

Comment: Hey AlexP, yeah I know I could do this, but I want excatly that almost every post would be different size and that all posts would stick together and there wouldnt be any white space between line-break

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.post{
position: absolute;
}
```

and re-adjust your divs positions

Answer (score 0):

Edit class `.singlepost-masonry` it has white background with padding and border with shadow if you delete them, there will be no white space. Press `shift+ctrl+I` in your browser and try to customise it.